# How do I configure ADFS to be an Issue Provider and return an e-mail claim?

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs

I have followed several tutorials like this one: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg188595.aspx in an attempt to setup my local ADFS server to give my authenticated application an e-mail claim.

However, the only claims I have received from the authenticated application are below:

http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string

http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/windows

http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime

What I am attempting to do is to setup our adfs server to be an Idp where our local app can direct the user to it, they can sign in if needed, then the application will verify authentication and read the e-mail claim to know who the user is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I was not aware but our internal domain/active directory does not act as our e-mail provider so my active directory ID did not have an e-mail address assigned to it. My mgr put the e-mail address in there and wallah, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

That's for a pass-through scenario.

In your RP add LDAP claims for email etc. and you'll see them.